# Unlimited quantifiers in a complex lookbehind

Tags: java, regex, lookbehind

I'm having a lot of trouble writing this regular expression:

```
(?<=\s+|^\s*|\(\s*|\.)(?:item|item1|item2)(?=\s+|\s*$|\s*\)|\.)
```

It works very well on my regex editor (Expresso) and in the .NET environment, but in the Java environment (JRE 1.6.0.25 using Eclipse Helios R2) it doesn't work because the `Pattern.compile()` method throws a "Syntax error U_REGEX_LOOK_BEHIND_LIMIT" exception.

That's because the look behind pattern `(?<=\s+|^\s*|\(\s*|\.)` must have a defined limit (unlimited quantifiers such as `*` and `+` are not allowed here as far as I know).

I also tried to specify the range of repetition in this way with no luck:

```
(?<=\s{0,1000}|^\s{0,1000}|\(\s{0,1000}|\.)(?:item|item1|item2)(?=\s+|\s*$|\s*\)|\.)
```

So, how can I write an identical regex that works even on Java environment?
I can't believe that there's no workaround for this kind of common situation....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that the lookbehind will only look as far behind as it must.  For example, `(?<=\s+)` will be satisfied if the previous character is a space; it doesn't need to look any farther back.

The same is true of your lookbehind.  If it's not the beginning of the string and the previous character is not whitespace, an open-parenthesis or a period, there's no point looking any farther back.  It's equivalent to this:

```
(?<=^|[\s(.])
```

Your lookahead can be condensed in the same way.  If it's not the end of the string, and the next character is not whitespace, a close-parenthesis or a period, there's no point looking any further:

```
(?=[\s).]|$)
```

So the final regex is:

```
(?<=^|[\s(.])(?:item|item1|item2)(?=[\s).]|$)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! i tried your regex and it seem to be good! I have to change my approach and pay more attantion while writing lookaround regex code...your help is very usefull!